# ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero in python

Tags: python, math

I was writing a program; for finding Greatest common divisor
but I receive this an error

```
h = 0
def GCD(num1, num2):
    if num1 == num2:
        return num1, num2
    elif num1 < num2:
        h = num1
        num1 = num2
        num2 = h
        while num1 % num2 != 0:
            num1 = num2
            num2 = num1 % num2
        return num2
print (GCD(12, 18))
```

and here is the error I received that
`ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` 
in this line `while num1 % num2 != 0:`

full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\projects\*****.py", line 13, in <module>
    print (GCD(12,18))
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\projects\*****.py", line 9, in GCD
    while num1 % num2 != 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

***I'm grateful for any helps***

Comment: `num2 = num1 % num2` this will eventually set `num2` to `0`.

Comment: @Selcuk there's nothing eventual about it, it happens the very first time.

Comment: @MarkRansom True, I didn't see the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [j1-lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11450820/j1-lee) you are *guaranteeing* that `num2` will become zero with this sequence of operations:

```
            num1 = num2
            num2 = num1 % num2
```

You probably wanted to use the original value of `num1` in that second line.  Fortunately Python makes that easy using tuple packing and unpacking:

```
            num1, num2 = num2, num1 % num2
```

The calculations on the right side will be performed before any assignments are made.

Comment: tnx 
i didn't think about that